# Фильтр по дате в Excel

Tags: excel

Почему-то никак не удается сделать простейшую вещь - имеется таблица, первый столбец - дата и время. Нужно видеть только данные за последние 50 дней (например).

Фильтры по дате либо предлагают конкретные сроки - типа, текущий месяц, либо после конкретной даты. При попытках использовать в поле "после" чего-то типа `=СЕГОДНЯ()-50`, убирает все записи.

В Excel я полный нуль, так что подскажите, как такое сделать корректно. Один раз было нужно похожее - там я сделал условное форматирование, выделив цветом нужное (там формулы работают), а потом отфильтровав по цвету. Тут таблица не моя и уже разукрашенная.

Сейчас выкрутился, введя столбец с `=СЕГОДНЯ()-A###` и фильтруя по нему - но это же тоже некрасиво. Я понимаю, что я забиваю гвозди микроскопом. Как забивать гвозди правильно? :)

P.S. Позволил себе спросить здесь, потому как тут явно нужно работать с формулами, т.е. программировать :)

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [PowerQuery](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE-Microsoft-Power-Query-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605), сам с экселем не дружу, но эта штука помогает творить чудеса )

Comment: В принципе, вариант с дополнительным столбцом довольно логичный. Сами по себе фильтры, к сожалению, не позволяют делать сложные запросы.

Comment: Визуальным средством построения фильтра параметр `Criteria` в метод `Range.AutoFilter` передаётся как строковый литерал. Поэтому писАть туда функции листа бессмысленно. Решением может быть построение требуемого фильтра из программного VBA-модуля (макроса) по какому-то событию (например, по двойному или правому клику в определённой ячейке), при этом даже можно вывести свою форму, запрашивающую дополнительные сведения (скажем, продолжительность периода).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем просто не получится.

**Вариант1. Доп. столбец**

Т.к. функция *СЕГОДНЯ()* летуча (пересчитывается при любых изменениях на листе), ее лучше держать в одной ячейке и ссылаться на нее. Для удобства назначить ячейку для ввода периода дат. Фильтровать по доп. столбцу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант2. Расширенный фильтр**

Выделить заголовок фильтруемого столбца (или диапазон дат с заголовком), вкладка *Данные-Фильтр-Дополнительно*. Задать параметры фильтрации. Фильтровать можно на месте или в отдельном диапазоне.

Обязательно наличие отдельного диапазона условий: текст из заголовка фильтруемого столбца и критерий. Критерий можно задавать текстом с операторами сравнения. Расширенный фильтр интересен тем, что можно объединять условия по *И* или *ИЛИ*, размещая дополнительные условия ниже в столбце или рядом с таким же заголовком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант3. Расширенный фильтр макросом**

Макрорекодером записать действия по фильтрации расширенным фильтром, подкорректировать запись (макрорекодер пишет не все и много лишнего) - получится макрос, который можно запускать одним кликом:

```
Sub AdvancedFilter()
Dim lRw As Long
    With ActiveSheet
         ' последняя заполненная ячейка диапазона пользователя'
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        ' автофильтр: данные из столбца А, критерии D1:D2, поместить в F4'
        ' если нужны только уникальные дата-время - Unique:=False'
        Range("A4:A" & lRw).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                        CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:D2"), _
                        CopyToRange:=Range("F4"), Unique:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Макрос не видит дату, записанную текстом, поэтому формула условия другая, с отображением даты в числовом формате.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Alt+F11* - вход в  редактор *VBA*. Слева дерево проекта. *Insert-Module* - добавится общий модуль, где разместить макрос.

На листе создать кнопку и назначить ей макрос.